# Unable to pull and push to git via cmd

Tags: windows, git, github, cmd, git-bash

I got a problem. A am trying to learn git. I initialized my local repo, added everything, committed. I'm using atom cmd and bash, because there are some commands, that are unavailable in atom cmd. I created an ssh-key, added it and everything works fine. I am trying to synchronize everything and pull from the remote repo, but I am getting an error:

```
 PS C:\Users\keldranase\Documents\Obsidian Vaults> git pull origin  master --allow-unrelated-histories
 git@github.com: Permission denied (publickey).
 fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
```

At the same time, when I am doing same using bash, everything works fine:

```
 keldranase@DESKTOP-SH6U8NC MINGW64 /c/users/keldranase/documents/Obsidian Vaults (master)
 $ git pull origin master --allow-unrelated-histories
```

Whats the reason behind this? How to solve this problem? What am I doing wrong? Your help would be appreciated.

Screenshot:
[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 1):

Your SSH key is not loaded. You need **first to start the ssh client** and then add the ssh key, you can find more information [here](https://docs.github.com/en/github/authenticating-to-github/generating-a-new-ssh-key-and-adding-it-to-the-ssh-agent). And here you can find some useful troubleshooting information for your error and other issues you might experience with SSH - [Error Permission Denied](https://docs.github.com/en/github/authenticating-to-github/error-permission-denied-publickey).